# Is it possible to use geofencing in Android Google Maps to dynamically display markers when near locations?

Tags: android, google-maps

Like the title says, I would like to know if it's possible to use geofencing to display marker locations when a user is within range of a location?

I would like the ability for the marker to "pop-up" when the user gets close to said location, and then disappear if they move out of range of said location.

I've already implemented a way to constantly check the user's current location a `LocationListner`, but not sure if this is possible.

Does the Google Maps API allow users to do this? If so, can someone provide me an example?

Thanks

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? Geofencing API provide callbacks that notify you of proximity, and you're free to do anything you want based on this information.

Comment: can you provide an example? Thanks